# GET Rest API NodeJS data export

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, rest

I would like to return if true or false the user exists by retrieving the information of a user, if there is information then we return true, otherwise we return false. The problem is that in my `res.on('end')` I recover the user data well, but it is impossible to recover his data outside of this function. Do you have an idea ?

`this.api.getEnv()` = http (dev) or https (prod)

```js
        GetUserById = function (id) {

        const req = this.api.getEnv().request(this.api.ApiHeader('/user/' + this.PlayerIdentifiers(id, "license"), 'GET'), res => {

            let body = '';
            res.on('data', d => {
                body += d;
            });

            res.on('end', function () {
                const user = JSON.parse(body);
                console.log(user);
            });

            if (user) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: The constant `user` is created inside the `res.on('end')` function, so it is not visible outside that function. To make it work, maybe you need to put `res.send` inside the `res.on('end')` function? Something like `res.send(user ? true : false);` just after `console.log(user);`

Comment: Hello, thanks you for your response. I come to a new error: res.send is not a function.

Comment: @Evert, thank you very much, that's exactly what i needed.

Answer (score -2):

```
res.on('end', function () {
  const user = JSON.parse(body);
  console.log(user);
  if (user) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});
```